# Find automatically the index of a list item which is contained in a specific pandas column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I am trying to find automatically without using for the index of a list item which is contained in a specific pandas column per row.

Imagine that I have a list with `names = ["U9", "Z9", "H10"]` and a pandas dataframe with a column that contains the following

```
dat['col1'] = ["U9", "U9", "U9", "Z9", "Z9", "H10", "H10", "H10", "H10", "H10"]
```

I am trying to replace the first code with the second one which starts from mask however I have the following error.

```py
for i in range(len(dat)):
    index = names.index(dat['col1'][i])
    if index < len(names)-1:
        dat.loc[i, 'col2'] = names[index + 1]
    else:
        break

mask = []

for i in range(len(dat)):
    mask.append(names.index(dat['col1'][i]) < len(names) - 1)


dat['col2'] = np.where(mask, names[names.index(dat['col1'])+1], np.NaN)
```

The error that I get is

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This happens because `names[names.index(dat['col1'])+1]` is not iterating for each row in the `dat['col1']`.

So what I want is to iterate through rows in pandas without using the for which is mentioned below and assign to `dat['col2']` the values of `dat['col1']` but shifted. The expected result should be like

```
dat['col2'] = ["Z9", "Z9", "Z9", "H10", "H10", nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) after creating a dict from the list:

```
d={a:b for a,b in zip(names,names[1:])}
#{'U9': 'Z9', 'Z9': 'H10'}
dat['col2']=dat.col1.map(d)
```

---

```
0     Z9
1     Z9
2     Z9
3    H10
4    H10
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
```

Using [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) you can also get index vs values:

```
pd.Series(d).get(dat.col1)
```

---

```
col1
U9      Z9
U9      Z9
U9      Z9
Z9     H10
Z9     H10
H10    NaN
H10    NaN
H10    NaN
H10    NaN
H10    NaN
```